# What is the lowest possible rating you can achieve (if any)?

Tags: rating

This question comes from a lack of understanding of how ratings work.
What is the lowest rating you can get ( or does it never stop decreasing )?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Elo system is implemented in its purest form, there is no theoretical lower limit for a rating.

Practically though, every chess organisation implements its rating system a bit differently and often there are rating floors that constitute the lowest possible rating.

The USCF for example seems to have a [rating floor of 100](http://mdchess.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=21:how-to-find-a-players-new-uscf-rating-after-an-mca-scholastic-tournament&catid=9&Itemid=7).